# Problems with python when trying to control a Nao robot with a Kinect

Tags: kinect, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My team is trying to implement the nao_openni package from WPI(code [here](https://github.com/wpi-ros-pkg-git/nao_openni#readme)). Following the readme file we've gotten to step 5e, where we get a python import error.

"$ rospack find [PACKAGE]" finds the all packages that it says it depends on.

"$ echo $PYTHONPATH" returns:

/opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/roslib/src:/home/[username]/Desktop/aldebaran-sdk-1.6.13-linux-i386/lib

The error when running:

"$ ./nao_ni_walker.py" (and ./nao_walker.py and ./nao_sensors.py) is:

File "./nao_walker.py", line 51, in 
from nao_ctrl.msg import MotionCommandBtn
ImportError: No module named nao_ctrl.msg

We aren't very familiar with Python, I've been trying to read about it to figure out what's going on but it hasn't been working so far.

We're fairly new to ROS, so any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9092/problems-with-python-when-trying-to-control-a-nao-robot-with-a-kinect/) by [tecedge](https://answers.ros.org/users/88/tecedge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tecedge](https://answers.ros.org/users/88/tecedge/) on 2011-02-22**:
That worked for that error. Thanks again everyone. We're on to another error now though. If we can't figure it out in a few days I'll be back.

**Comment by [tecedge](https://answers.ros.org/users/88/tecedge/) on 2011-02-16**:
Alright. I have to go to class right now but I'll try that later. Thanks a lot for the help everyone.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-16**:
You likely don't have permissions to write to that directory (check with 'ls -lh  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/nao_0.2'). If you installed nao_ctrl from a source checkout, you should install it to a directory that you have write access to. You could also try running 'sudo make' to force a make to happen.

**Comment by [tecedge](https://answers.ros.org/users/88/tecedge/) on 2011-02-16**:
When running rosmake nao_ctrl there are errors that say gcc is broken, the interesting part can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ZmqKa0vJ. EDIT: There seems to be something wrong with the permissions too.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-16**:
If you're unsure, it's best to just run the command again.

**Comment by [tecedge](https://answers.ros.org/users/88/tecedge/) on 2011-02-16**:
I believe my teammate did it before, is there a way that to check to see that it's been done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you done 'make' in the nao_ctrl package (or 'rosmake nao_ctrl') -- if not, you won't have the message headers generated yet.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2